# Meteor Amazon s3 delete image

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I have successfully uploaded an image to amazon s3 with this meteor package
https://github.com/Lepozepo/S3 Now I am trying to delete the file, which I am getting a error on.

This is the documentation for the s3.delete code

> S3.delete(path,callback)
>
> This function permanently destroys a file located in your S3 bucket.
>
> Parameters:
>
> path: Must be in this format ("/folder/other_folder/file.extension").
>   So basically always start with "/" and never end with "/". This is
>   required.
>
> callback: A function that is run after the delete operation
>   is complete returning an Error as the first parameter (if there is
>   one), and a Result as the second.

This is my upload and delete code

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  "click button.upload": function(){
        var files = $("input.file_bag")[0].files

        S3.upload({
                files:files,
                path:"uploads"
            },function(e,r){
                console.log(r);

        delete_url = r.relative_url;

        console.log(delete_url);
        });
    },
  "click button.delete": function(){

    S3.delete({
      path:delete_url
      },function(e,r){
        console.log(e);
        console.log(r);
    });


    }
});
```

The error I get when hitting the delete button.

```
errorClass {isClientSafe: true, error: 400, reason: "Match failed", details: undefined, message: "Match failed [400]", …}
details
:
undefined
error
:
400
errorType
:
"Meteor.Error"
isClientSafe
:
true
message
:
"Match failed [400]"
reason
:
"Match failed"
stack
:
"Error↵    at Connection._livedata_result (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=14d966b7972bd95a1f7015fec9ac340f10508a44:4823:23)↵    at onMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=14d966b7972bd95a1f7015fec9ac340f10508a44:3528:206)↵    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=14d966b7972bd95a1f7015fec9ac340f10508a44:2908:9↵    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)↵    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?hash=cde485f60699ff9aced3305f70189e39c665183c:149:11)↵    at SockJS.self.socket.onmessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=14d966b7972bd95a1f7015fec9ac340f10508a44:2907:43)↵    at SockJS.REventTarget.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=14d966b7972bd95a1f7015fec9ac340f10508a44:142:28)↵    at SockJS._dispatchMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=14d966b7972bd95a1f7015fec9ac340f10508a44:1309:14)↵    at SockJS._didMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=14d966b7972bd95a1f7015fec9ac340f10508a44:1375:26)↵    at WebSocket.that.ws.onmessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=14d966b7972bd95a1f7015fec9ac340f10508a44:1531:21)"
__proto__
:
Error
```

**Update**
This is the error I got on the server in terminal side

```
Exception while invoking method '_s3_delete' Error: Match error: Expected string, got object
```

Comment: Could you insert `console.log(delete_url);` after upload and before delete?

Comment: Yes I can and it gives me the path `/uploads/image-name.jpg` just as the documentation asks for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call it like this:

```
S3.delete(delete_url, function() { ... });
```

First parameter should be url itself, not the object like in your example.